# Looping through Wordpress Posts - Output using Bootstrap

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a custom wordpress theme using the Bootstrap Framework.
I need the loop through the blog posts in rows of 2.

The HTML output I need as follows:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 blog-item text-center">
                <div class="blog-padding blog-indx-panel">
                    <div><a href="link to post here"><img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/featured-image1.jpg"></a></div>
                    <h3>POST TITLE #1</h3>
                    <p class="blog-date">10 FEBRUARY 2015</p>
                    <p>Blog Excerpt Shown Here</p>
                    <div><a class="btn btn-default btn-text" href="linktoposthere" role="button">Read Full Post</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 blog-item text-center">
                <div class="blog-padding blog-indx-panel">
                    <div><a href="link to post here"><img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/featured-image1.jpg"></a></div>
                    <h3>POST TITLE #1</h3>
                    <p class="blog-date">16 FEBRUARY 2015</p>
                    <p>Blog Excerpt Shown Here</p>
                    <div><a class="btn btn-default btn-text" href="#linktoposthere" role="button">Read Full Post</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But I'm unsure on how to create a php loop in wordpress to get the desired output.

Any ideas?

Comment: What code do you have for your loop so far? You will want to use the modulo operator to know when to open the div with the class row and when to close it.

Comment: @kel - The code I currently have is at http://pastebin.com/Vy8Z9Hiz
It's not correctly ending the </div> is there's an odd number of posts outputted.

Comment: Answered below, sorry it took so long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read up on the modulo operator. It's really helpful for these situations. Below I have two versions, the top is documented and uses braces (makes it easier to read) and the bottom does the same thing in the least code.

**Way One**

```
<?php
// wp_query is used to get the post count in the loop
global $query_string, $wp_query;

// Define starting count
$counter = 1;

// Will output pagination set limit unless there are not enough posts, then it will output the remainder
$post_count = $wp_query->post_count;

if ( have_posts() ) {

  while ( have_posts() ) {

    the_post();

    // Checks to see if the current post is odd.
    // If it is, we open the div for the row.
    // Modulo give the remainder of the two numbers.
    if ($counter % 2 != 0) {
      echo '<div class="row">';
    }

    ?>

    <div class="col-md-6 blog-item text-center">
      <div class="postimage">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('category-thumbnail'); ?></a>
      </div>
      <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    </div>

    <?php

    // Is the post count even? We better close the div.
    // Also closes the div once we hit the last post in the loop.
    if ( $counter % 2 == 0 || $post_count == $counter ) {
      echo '</div>';
    }

    // Increment counter
    $counter++;

  }

}
```

**Way Two**

```
<?php
global $query_string, $wp_query;
$counter = 1;
$post_count = $wp_query->post_count;

if ( have_posts() ) :   while( have_posts() ) : the_post();

  if ($counter % 2 != 0)
    echo '<div class="row">';

  ?>

  <div class="col-md-6 blog-item text-center">
    <div class="postimage">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('category-thumbnail'); ?></a>
    </div>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
  </div>

  <?php

  if ( $counter % 2 == 0 || $post_count == $counter )
    echo '</div>';

  $counter++;

endwhile; endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="row">

<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
     while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
?>

<div class="col-md-6 blog-item text-center">
            <div class="blog-padding blog-indx-panel">
                <div><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); ?>"></a></div>
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <p class="blog-date"><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></p>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?> </p>
                <div><a class="btn btn-default btn-text" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" role="button">Read Full Post</a></div>
            </div>
</div>

<?php
    } // end while
} // end if
?>

</div>
```